# React useEffect, dependency list not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-effects

I'm sure I have got the wrong understanding on this.  I have the following component

```
const Comp = () => {
    const filter = 'a';

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('executing effect');
      loadFriends();
    }, [filter]);


    return (
      <Div>
        {friendsFilter}
      </Div>
    );
  };
```

Now as per my understanding, since the dependency list on `useEffect` is `filter` react should not run the effect when the component gets rendered again ? However it seems to run it.  Am I understanding something wrong here?

Comment: Use componentDidMount() for re rendering

Comment: I'm not trying to use componentDidMount or re-render.  I'm trying to ask why it runs the effect even when `filter` value has not changed ?

Comment: There has to be something else going on here, I'm sure this is stripped down code, can you provide a more verbose example?

Comment: What is your loadFriends() doing? Can you post full code?

Comment: share the code of loadFriends() block. Probably its altering the value of filter.

Comment: add your full code for better understanding what you are doing in friendsFilter.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want it to run once, use an empty array for the dependency value instead of `[filter]'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have tested your use-case but it doesn't call the useEffect block.

Here is the code which I've tested.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Comp = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const filter = "a";

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("executing effect");
    //loadFriends();
  }, [filter]);

  return (
    <div>
      Div
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> Click me</button>
      Count: {count}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Comp;
```

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-9wglw) 
Even changing the count the component re-rendered but doesn't call the useEffect block.

Most probably there's something happening in `loadFriends()` which is changing the value of the filter.

[Read more about useEffect here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: Thanks for this, even if `loadFriends` is changing anything, since the `filter` is hard-coded shouldn't the useEffect run only once ?

Comment: Well if you could share the code inside `loadFriends` i can give you a better answer. As the code above works perfectly fine without `loadFriends`.